# Remove icon from menu

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop

I uninstalled an app called 'Ark' months ago but the icon still remains on my menu.

[image]

I have run both `ls -la /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i 'ark'` and `ls -la ~/.local/share/applications/ | grep -i 'ark'` but nothing happens. I also tried running `sudo xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate --mode system` but still no luck.

When I right-click on the icon and press 'details' I get this message:

[image]

Can you please help me get rid of it?

Comment: How did you install it and how did you uninstall it?

Comment: Use `locate` (read `man locate`), `locate '*.desktop' | grep -i ark`.

Comment: I installed and uninstalled using the Ubuntu software app.
Waltinator, the file is located in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/ark_org.kde.ark.desktop`. I tried removing it through the file explorer but the option doesn't appear. Is there a command line I can use to remove it?

Comment: I removed it using sudo rm! OMG, I'm so happy, thanks!